# Return Result from a python script using SL4A back to Android App

Tags: android, python, sl4a

i am trying to get result from a python script using (SL4A) after calling startActivityForResult() in my java android app. However i always get a null intent in my onActivityResult()

***Running the python Script from my Java app***

```
public static Intent buildStartInBackgroundIntent(File script) {
final ComponentName componentName = Constants.SL4A_SERVICE_LAUNCHER_COMPONENT_NAME;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(componentName);
intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_LAUNCH_BACKGROUND_SCRIPT);
intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SCRIPT_PATH, script.getAbsolutePath());
return intent;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout_running);
String pythonScript = "/sdcard/sl4a/scripts/pythondecoder.py";
Intent intent = buildStartInBackgroundIntent(new File(pythonScript));
intent.putExtra("serialinput","MessageIn");
startActivityForResult(intent, PYTHONSCRIPTDECODE);
}
```

***Receiving the Result from pythonscript upon completion***

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
switch(requestCode){
case  PYTHONSCRIPTDECODE:
Log.d("Robin_ValueCheck","Python reply me -> "+data.getExtras().getString("SCRIPT_RESULT"));
break;
}
```

***however upon Activity result, Logcat Error Msg.***

```
08-27 09:56:41.945: E/AndroidRuntime(29438): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3050, result=0, data=null} to activity {xxx.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.CustomLayoutViewer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

***This is my python script, run by SL4A***

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
mIntent = droid.getIntent().result
Extras = mIntent["extras"]
Input = Extras["serialinput"]

Result_OK = -1
resultData = "Returned from SL4a Script!"
droid.setResultString(Result_OK, resultData)
```

When the python script exits, my onActivityResult is notified as seen by REQUEST = 3050. However the Intent that should comes back with it is NULL.  I have already called setResultString() in my python script. Any idea what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately this does not work, see also issue 239... you might want to star that issue there: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/issues/detail?id=239

Comment: The above link doesnt work. Please follow the link. "Allow scripts to exit with a result" https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a/issues/262